# Parsing Json message with sscanf()

Tags: c, json, udp, scanf

My application receives a `JSon` message via `UDP` from coordinates of an object as follows:

```
{
    "FRAME1": {
        "X": "-0.885498",
        "Y": "-0.205078",
        "Z": "0.628174"
    },
    "FRAME2": {
        "X": "1.70898",
        "Y": "-5.67627",
        "Z": "0.305176"
    },
    "ID": "DEVICE9",
    "TS": "7.9900"
}
```

I need to read the coordinates from `FRAME1` and `FRAME2` (X,Y,Z values of each frame). The `Json` message is stored in `char[] msg`. I use these the following lines of code two get the coordinates of `FRAME1`:

```
char Xc[32], Yc[32], Zc[32];
sscanf (msg,
        "{\"X\":\"%s\",\"Y\":\"%s\",\"Z\":\"%s\"}",
        Xc, Yc, Zc);
```

I display the stored value with `printf` as:

```
printf("X coordinate is: %s\n" , Xc);
```

The output, however is strange:

```
X coordinate is: |-
```

What is wrong in the format provided for `sscanf()`?

Comment: Use some JSON library but not sscanf.

Comment: Do you check the return value from `sscanf`? Maybe you should!

Comment: @Michael Walz: Do you suggest anything in specific?

Comment: Shouldn't the `sscanf` format string contain some whitespace between the colons and the double quotes?

Comment: @QuestionMark [SimpleJSON](https://github.com/MJPA/SimpleJSON) is quite good.

Comment: Software recommendations are generally off-topic on SO, but http://json.org might be a good place to start.

Comment: @QuestionMark or for C (not C++) [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)

Comment: Just because your format string contains e.g. `%s"` won't magically make `%s` not eat the quote. it doesn't work like that. You can *probably* use character groups, i.e. `\"%[^\"]\"` to capture a quoted string, but it's iffy and will break if there's escaped quotes (which I think JSON supports).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sscanf` with the %n specifier and `strcmp` could be used to parse the string. `%n` captures the number of characters used in the scan.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int index = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    char sub[300] = "";
    char Xc[32] = "";
    char Yc[32] = "";
    char Zc[32] = "";
    char msg[] = {
    "{\n\
    \"FRAME1\": {\n\
        \"X\": \"-0.885498\",\n\
        \"Y\": \"-0.205078\",\n\
        \"Z\": \"0.628174\"\n\
    },\n\
    \"FRAME2\": {\n\
        \"X\": \"1.70898\",\n\
        \"Y\": \"-5.67627\",\n\
        \"Z\": \"0.305176\"\n\
        },\n\
        \"ID\": \"DEVICE9\",\n\
        \"TS\": \"7.9900\"\n\
    }\n"
    };

    offset = 0;
    while ( ( sscanf ( msg + offset, "%299s%n", sub, &index)) == 1) {
        offset += index;
        if ( strcmp (sub, "\"X\":" ) == 0) {
            if ( ( sscanf ( msg + offset, "%31s%n", Xc, &index)) == 1) {
                offset += index;
                printf ( "Xc is %s\n", Xc);
            }
        }
        if ( strcmp (sub, "\"Y\":" ) == 0) {
            if ( ( sscanf ( msg + offset, "%31s%n", Yc, &index)) == 1) {
                offset += index;
                printf ( "Yc is %s\n", Yc);
            }
        }
        if ( strcmp (sub, "\"Z\":" ) == 0) {
            if ( ( sscanf ( msg + offset, "%31s%n", Zc, &index)) == 1) {
                offset += index;
                printf ( "Zc is %s\n", Zc);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above sscanf's for the coordinates will include the quotes. This could be used to remove the quotes

```
if ( ( sscanf ( msg + offset, " \"%31[^\"]%*s%n", Xc, &index)) == 1) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet that compiles! In `sscanf ( msg + offset, "%31s%n", Xc, &index)` what is the general case if `Xc`, `Yc` and `Zc` have different unknown lengths?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use `strtok()` instead and use the colons as delims or something? Not sure if it makes your life any easier, but I know that strtok() is generally recommended over the *scanf() family of functions.